# send and receive via Serial port Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, serial-port, uart

I have a application running on windows, which will send data over serial port.
Here is the code:

```
m_hCommPort= ::CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM3",
        GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);

    if(m_hCommPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        printf("COM error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    config.DCBlength = sizeof(config);


    if((GetCommState(m_hCommPort, &config) == 0))
    {
        CloseHandle(m_hCommPort);
        printf("Get configuration port has a problem.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    config.BaudRate = 9600;
    config.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    config.Parity = PARITY_NONE; 
    config.ByteSize = DATABITS_8;
    config.fDtrControl = 0;
    config.fRtsControl = 0;

    if (!SetCommState(m_hCommPort, &config))
    {
        CloseHandle(m_hCommPort);
        printf( "Failed to Set Comm State Reason: %d\n",GetLastError());
        return E_FAIL;
    }
```

Here is the code for Send only (Working) (continuously sending )

```
while(1)
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        int isWritten = WriteFile(m_hCommPort, txData, 9/*(DWORD)sizeof(txData)*/, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
            printf("isWritten: %d, dwBytesWritten: %d \n", isWritten, dwBytesWritten);

    }
```

After this I have added code for Receive data too, then send is NOT WORKING. I mean not able to send data over UART. WriteFile() seems not executed, its stuck.
Here I have added a thread to receive data, is thread causing the problem ? or do I need to do something else ?

```
void ReceiverThread(void *param)
{
    DWORD dwRead=0;
    BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
    OVERLAPPED osReader = {0};

    osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (osReader.hEvent == NULL)
        printf("Error creating overlapped event; abort.\n");
    while(1)
    {
        if (!ReadFile(m_hCommPort, &Byte, 1, &dwRead, &osReader)) {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)     // read not delayed?
                printf("Error in communications; report it.\n");
            else
                fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
        }
        else {    

            rxData[rxHeadIndex++]= Byte;
            rxHeadIndex = (rxHeadIndex) & QUEUE_MASK;
        }


    }

}


SetCommMask (m_hCommPort, EV_RXCHAR/ | EV_ERR); //receive character event


    _beginthread(ReceiverThread,0,NULL); 


    while(1)
    {
        Sleep(5000);
        int isWritten = WriteFile(m_hCommPort, txData, 9/*(DWORD)sizeof(txData)*/, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
            printf("isWritten: %d, dwBytesWritten: %d \n", isWritten, dwBytesWritten);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.
Ashok

Comment: There is a solution Event EV_RXCHAR, http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem a while ago.

I found out that `WriteFile(..)` blocks if a `ReadFile(..)` is currently in progress for a serial port. So that's a problem if `ReadFile(..)` blocks if there is no data to be read.

I've solved the problem by checking if there is data available within the serial buffer to be read by using the function [`ClearCommError(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa363180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This ensures that `ReadFile(..)` can read something immediately and does not unnecessarily block the device. Try changing your `ReceiverThread` into something like this:

```
void ReceiverThread(void *param)
{
    DWORD dwRead=0;
    COMSTAT comStat;
    char buffer[1024];

    while (m_hCommPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if ((ClearCommError(m_hCommPort, NULL, &comStat) != FALSE) && (comStat.cbInQue > 0))
        {
            /* todo: ensure buffer is big enough to contain comStat.cbInQue bytes! */

            if (ReadFile(m_hCommPort, buffer, comStat.cbInQue, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
            {
                /* do something with data in buffer */
            }
        }

        /* avoid busy-wait */
        if (comStat.cbInQue == 0)
        {
            SleepEx(1, FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

This way `ReadFile(..)` is only called if data is available and meanwhile `WriteFile(..)` can send data without being blocked.

Unfortunately I've not been able to make `ClearCommError(..)` blocking so I used the `SleepEx(1, FALSE);` work-around to avoid a busy-wait and therefore prefenting the `ReceiverThread` to eat up the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try this and let you know the results.

Comment: its working but received buffer should handled in else part of if (!ReadFile(m_hCommPort, buffer, comStat.cbInQue, &dwRead, NULL)).

Comment: @Asht Houups, yes, of course! I've changed that in my original post... Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This seems to be the generic solution, as overlapping is widely not supported.

Answer (score 2):

```
  config.fDtrControl = 0;
  config.fRtsControl = 0;
```

These settings turn the DTR and RTS handshake lines off.  Most serial devices pay attention to these signals.  They won't send anything when your DTR signal is off, assuming that the machine is not powered up.  And won't send anything when your RTS signal is off, assuming that the machine is not ready to receive any data.

So what you observed is entirely normal.

Since the device appears to be "normal" and *does* pay attention to the handshake lines, you'll want to configure the DCB to let the device driver automatically control these signals.  Fix:

```
  config.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
  config.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
```

Also the default for terminal emulators like Putty and HyperTerminal.  Use such a program first to ensure that the wiring and device are functional.  If you can't get any device data to show up in such a program then it won't work with your program either.  If this all checks out then also set the fDsrSensitivity, fOutxCtsFlow and fOutxDsrFlow properties to TRUE so that you will, in turn, pay attention to the handshake signals of the device.